# Lazy Loading with multiple files (1 per language) for a module

Tags: angular

I'm on Angular 13 and I'm actually working to implement the lazy loading.
It's work perfectly, except the translations.

In fact, in my case, the translations are generated in the back-end: in the main.js, we have all the key to translate, and for each languages, we have a new file (main-"lang".js) generated.
So I apply the same mechanism for the lazy modules, and I have my differents files generated (module_name_ts.js with the key, module_name_ts-en.js with the translations in english...)

But, I don't know how to specify to "select" an other file when I go to a page with lazy module (it's the original file of module with keys which is selected).

```
    {
    path: 'core.menu',
    loadChildren: () => import('./menu/menu.module').then(m => m.MenuModule)
},
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you use [`@ngx-translate/core`](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for this?

Comment: If you needed to load translations based on lazy loaded modules, you can use Transloco : https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/lazy-load/scope-configuration. But I don't really see the point of switching Modules on runtime for handling the translations. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu No. Translations are generated in the back with our own method.

Comment: @AlainBoudard yes maybe we'll use that if there is no solution. Like I said, we generate a file for each language (main-fr.js, main-en.js...).

Comment: I see the point of generating translations, really, now is there a reason why you generate .js files and not simply the translations ?